# php Activating On Page Load While Inside Of onsubmit

Tags: php, onsubmit

I have a php function to create a file in a directory on submission of a form.
The code is:

```
<form id="myForm" onSubmit="<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $directory = __DIR__ . "/images/"; $filecount = 0; $files = glob($directory . "*");  if ($files){ 
    $filecount = count($files); }
    $filecount = $filecount + 1;
    $pagename = 'image_'.$filecount;

    $newFileName = './images/'.$pagename;
    $newFileContent = 'Page Content';
    if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    } else {
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    }
?>">
       <input placeholder="Username 0/25" name="user" id="user" maxlength="25" required>
       <input placeholder="Password 0/45" name="password" id="password" maxlength="45" required>
       <input placeholder="Image Name" name="name" id="name">
       <input type="file" placeholder="Image" accept="image/*" name="img" required>
       <button type="submit">Upload</button>
       </form>
```

The problem is that it auto activates on page load.. is there a way to fix that

Comment: Your code is simply wrong. You can't run PHP code within a Javascript event handler. Javascript is running in the browser and PHP is run on the server. The way to do this is to use AJAX to make a request to the server and run your PHP code there.

Comment: Do you have an example of this @TangentiallyPerpendicular ? Sorry I am very new to php and dont know javascript too well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that it auto activates on page load

to prevent auto loading the page when you press on submit, you could use this trick `"return false; \"..."` but it doesn't create the image file :/ just stop the page from action.

```php
    if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "return false; \"File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    } else {
    echo "return false; \" Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    }
```

I try to imitate you're project, however i used txt files instead of images.
I used [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

### index.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <form id="myForm">
            <button type="submit">create a file</button>
       </form>
       <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### script.js

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET','creating.php');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(xhr.readyState)
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        if(xhr.response.startsWith('Woow'))
          alert('File created successfully!');
        else
          alert('Something went wrong!');
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

### creating.php

```php
<?php
    $directory = __DIR__ . "/files/";
    $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*")) + 1;
    
    $newFileName = $directory.'txt_'.$filecount.'.txt';
    $newFileContent = "some text... in a file number $filecount.";
    
    if(file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent))
        echo "Woow!";
    else
        echo "Oups!";
?>
```